# How to made JAWS readout ListView Item use Server Annotation

Tags: c++, windows, listview, annotations, jaws-screen-reader

I have write a windows client, which UI framework is ATL/WTL. And There is a ListView (CListViewCtrl in ATL) with LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED style.

For support Accessibility tool JAWS.I Want Jaws read ListView item.

I follow the doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/server-annotation-sample

0.Impl of IAccPropServer for support GetPropValue .

```
class ListViewAccServer : public IAccPropServer
{
    ULONG   m_Ref;
    IAccPropServices * m_pAccPropSvc;

public:
 /*  skip over ListViewAccServer/ ~ListViewAccServer
     */
    static ListViewAccServer * CreateProvider(HWND hControl) 
    {
        ATL::CComPtr<IAccPropServices> pAccPropSvc;
        HRESULT hr = pAccPropSvc.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AccPropServices, NULL, CLSCTX_SERVER);
        if (hr == S_OK && pAccPropSvc)
        {
            ListViewAccServer * pLVServer = new (std::nothrow) ListViewAccServer(pAccPropSvc);
            if (pLVServer)
            {
                MSAAPROPID propid = PROPID_ACC_NAME;
                //pAccPropSvc->SetHwndPropServer(hControl, (DWORD)OBJID_CLIENT, CHILDID_SELF, &propid, 1, pLVServer, ANNO_CONTAINER);
                pAccPropSvc->SetHwndPropServer(hControl, (DWORD)OBJID_CLIENT, CHILDID_SELF, &propid, 1, pLVServer, ANNO_CONTAINER);
                pLVServer->Release();
            }
            return pLVServer;
        }
        return NULL;
    }

     /* skip over: Addref/Release/QI 
     */

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetPropValue(const BYTE * pIDString,
        DWORD dwIDStringLen, MSAAPROPID idProp, VARIANT * pvarValue,
        BOOL * pfGotProp)
    {
        if (!pfGotProp)
            return E_POINTER;

        pvarValue->vt = VT_EMPTY;
        *pfGotProp = FALSE;

        //HWND  hwnd;
        DWORD idObject;
        DWORD idChild;

        HWND dwHcontrol;

        if (S_OK != m_pAccPropSvc->DecomposeHwndIdentityString(pIDString,
            dwIDStringLen, &dwHcontrol, &idObject, &idChild))
        {
            return S_OK;
        }

        HWND Hwnd = dwHcontrol;
        // Only supply name string for child elements, not the listview itself

        if (idChild != CHILDID_SELF)
        {
            if (idProp == PROPID_ACC_NAME)//Jaws should read acc name?
            {
                CString str;
                str.Format(L"Line index %d", idChild);
                OutputDebugPrintfW(_T("GetPropValue str =%s\n"), str);
                BSTR bstr = ::SysAllocString((LPCTSTR)str.GetString());
                pvarValue->vt = VT_BSTR;
                pvarValue->bstrVal = bstr;

                *pfGotProp = TRUE;
            }
        }


        return S_OK;
    }
};
```

1.initUI

```cpp
        //if Set 'LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED',JAWS will read onDraw Item "Dummy List Item"
        m_lvMain.Create(m_hWnd, rc, NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN |
            LVS_REPORT | LVS_AUTOARRANGE | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | LVS_SHAREIMAGELISTS | WS_TABSTOP|LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED,
            WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, LIST_ID);
        /*
        m_lvMain.Create(m_hWnd, rc, NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN |
            LVS_REPORT | LVS_AUTOARRANGE | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | LVS_SHAREIMAGELISTS | WS_TABSTOP ,
            WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, LIST_ID);
        */
        //otherwise JAWS will read Hello,Hello1,Hello2...
        m_lvMain.InsertColumn(0, _T("Column"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 200);
        m_lvMain.InsertItem(0, _T("Hello"));
        m_lvMain.InsertItem(0, _T("Hello1"));
        m_lvMain.InsertItem(0, _T("Hello2"));
        m_lvMain.InsertItem(0, _T("Hello3"));
```

2.Bind Listview m_hwnd with ListViewAccServer

```
        m_pAccServer = ListViewAccServer::CreateProvider(m_lvMain.m_hWnd);
```

3

```
    LRESULT OnDrawItem(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
        //LRESULT onDraw(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD wID, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)(lParam);
        //OutputDebugPrintfW(_T("OnDrawItem i = %d, %d, %08x \n"), pDIS->itemID, pDIS->itemData, pDIS->hwndItem);

        BOOL bSelected = ((pDIS->itemState & ODS_SELECTED) == ODS_SELECTED);
        BOOL bFocus = ((pDIS->itemState & ODS_FOCUS) == ODS_FOCUS);
        HDC hDC = pDIS->hDC;
        RECT rc = pDIS->rcItem;
        HBRUSH bg = (HBRUSH)(::GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));

        if (bSelected)
        {
            bg = (HBRUSH)(::GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH));
        }
        if (bFocus)
        {
            bg = (HBRUSH)(::GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH));
        }
        HPEN pn = (HPEN)(::GetStockObject(BLACK_PEN));
        ::SelectObject(hDC, bg);
        ::SelectObject(hDC, pn);
        ::SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(0, 0, 0));
        const wchar_t *text = L"Dummy List Item";
        ::Rectangle(hDC, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);
        ::DrawText(hDC, text, wcslen(text), &rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER);
        return S_OK;
    }
```

When use UP and down array By Keyboard alert in ListView items.I want Jaws read out "Line index i" in GetPropValue.
But 
1: If I set ListView with style:LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED.On some PC, Jaws will read out "Dummy List Item". On Some PC, It read nothing.

[image: Use LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED]

2: If remove style:LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED. Jaws will read out 'Hello','Hello1'...
[image: No LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED]

both 1 or 2 do not read out GetPropValue give string"Line index i".
The log shows GetPropValue  is be called:
GetPropValue str =Line index 1
GetPropValue str =Line index 2

My test PC machine OSs are Win10,Win7
So what's the problem?
Thanks a lot.

PS:At last , I found this:
 https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=73496
I can use Insert+6 to bring up the JAWS Configuration Manager.
- click OK to Add a New Configuration (for your application)
- in the Configuration Manager dialog, type "listv" in the filter to see the page containing the "Rely on MSAA for ListViews" checkbox.
- check "Rely on MSAA for ListViews"
- click OK to save and exit the Configuration Manager.

So Jaws default do not use MSAA to get information?